# How should I step down 220V (ac) to 180V for a DC motor?

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, step-down, scr

I have many treadmills motor of rating 180V 10A which I would like to use for power tools. Locally we have 220V ac 50Hz.

I thought of using iron-core transformers. But having one for 1800W+ is expensive and bulky.

There are also thoughts of using PWM. I know that high voltages probably help the motors overcome reactance quicker. But the pulsatile currents might decrease the torque. **Can this be ameliorated with capacitors or inductors? Or it might run into impracticably large values required?**

Another forum post points me to "single SCR in a phase-controlled half wave topology".

**What would be the best option? Please point me to a good direction.**

Comment: The best option would be to find a 220VAC motor. Failing that, find a 340/360VDC motor.

Comment: I would take that recommendation. In fact, my last question is about a 220VAC single phase motor. But I hope to come up with a good solution with 180V dc ones, because treadmills are easier to find than an ac motor (locally, at least).

Comment: 180VDC is approximately (for a certain definition of "approximately") what you would get if you rectified and filtered 120VAC, which is probably why it was used in the first place.

Comment: You could use a stepdown transformer of 220 to 40V(42V). Being 400VA. Connect the primary of the transformer directly to the mains and place the secondary winding in series with the mains in such a way that the voltage becomes 180V AC. After rectification of this voltage you have what you need for your motors.

Comment: @Ignacio: In countries with 220V 50Hz we do not have 120V or 127V ac.

Comment: @Decapod: I am aware. I am also aware of the fact that I don't know where the motors came from.

Comment: @Ignacio: From where the mains is 220VAC too.

Comment: Decapod's auto transformer method would actually need to step down to approx 128V AC to get 180V DC (rectification "multiplies" the RMS voltage by root 2) so you may as well use a 220 -> 120 standard transformer. I'd be looking around for a Switch Mode Power Supply with a variable output voltage that covers 180V.

Comment: @Ian: The RMS voltage multiplication by root 2 is trough if you use capacitors after rectification. In this case you leave them out

Comment: In fact I am from Hong Kong. The motors we have are usually from China. They are mostly rated at 180V (even the first-hand ones).

Comment: Something like this perhaps: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/220V-20A-SCR-DC-motor-controller/318107044.html?spm=2114.40010408.3.8.bp5I0r

Comment: If you don't use a transformer (stepdown or otherwise) your motor will be connected directly to mains, and that is a recipe for killing someone unless you know what you're doing. Do you know what you're doing?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Are you trying to suggest the **isolation**?

Comment: 180VDC is the standard rating for motors used an SCR speed control with 240VAC input. 90VDC is used with 120VAC input. KB Electronics is one reputable maker of DC motor speed controls.

Comment: @Spehro: What eats up that excess of voltage?

Comment: @Sphero: I looked at the KB Electronics site and learned that the DC voltage is indeed 180V. Learned something new again.

@ user2513881: Under SCR control there will be no excess voltage since the controller regulates the maximum averige voltage to the motor.

Comment: @user2513881 The controller eats it up by virtue of its variable trigger angle. It maintains the armature voltage to control the speed and torque. The maximum  possible average voltage from a full wave SCR controller with 220VAC in is about 195V.

Comment: @Spehro: does that imply I can hook up 4 SCR set at maximum, to get the right voltage? I would to see your expanded answer.

Comment: @user2513881 I don't really have an expanded answer. I think you should buy a speed controller. [Here](http://andysmachines.weebly.com/uploads/1/7/5/0/1750739/1986195.gif?619) is a schematic of a commercial one. There are a fair number of parts. Only two SCRs are required, the other two parts in the bridge are diodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as depicted in winny's comment.
You don't "Step down" 220 VAC to 180 VDC.
220 VAC Single Phase is a normal supply for a DC drive to deliver 180VDC output.
Using a drive, you will also get the benefits if an acceleration and deceleration ramp, current limiting (to protect the motor), and a simple variable speed control (a potentiometer).

If you are just going to run the motor directly off the line, a simple bridge rectifier would work, but will probably blow up due to the inrush current to start the motor.